# How do I run the Web3J Smart Contract example?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, web3-java

I'm trying to run the Web3j example available at https://github.com/web3j/sample-project-gradle

Unfortunately, there is hardly any information available on how to build and run the example, and newbies have to contend with learning Gradle in addition to the Web3j-Java interface.

I'm able to build the example (after creating a Wallet account with a JSON file, loading it with Rinkleby Ether and inserting my Infura API key into the Application file) as follows:

```
$ gradle build
```

which succeeds without errors. However, I am clueless on how to run the project...thanks in advance for any help.

s1b

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems ok with the your project. Have you tried "Run as a Java application" option from the Eclipse IDE? I am running my Java smart contract functions in this way.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using Eclipse. However, if it's working this way, it's likely to be doing something like "java -jar xxx.jar" or "java <classfile>". Will try.

Comment: I think that if you are using a IDE that is designed to run java applications, you should not have problem to run it, in the way the IDE offers